# Weighted eigenvector-entry sums of bipartite graphs

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Let $\lambda_m$ denote the $m$-th eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix $A$ of a bipartite graph $G$ of order $N$ and ${\bf v}_m$ the normalized eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_m$. I am looking for possible ways to evaluate or bound $\sum_{m=1}^N {\bf v}_m(i)/\lambda_m$ for a node $i$ without a priori knowledge of the spectrum and eigenvectors. One may ignore $m$ for which $\lambda_m=0$ in the sum. I am hoping that I can exploit the symmetry of the eigenvalue spectrum and the properties of eigenvectors of bipartite graphs (like the ones mentioned in [the answer to this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/112404/nice-eigenvectors-for-square-of-adjacency-matrix-of-a-bipartite-graph)) to achieve this. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: What is **the** corresponding eigenvector?

Comment: ${\bf v}_m$ is the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_m$.

Comment: You missed the **the** in my question. First, you have a whole eigenspace. Second, even if each eigenvalue is simple (which is often not the case), how do you normalize $v$? The bound that you are seeking obviously depends on this normalization. (And, if $\lambda$ is multiple, on the choice of a basis.)

Comment: As for normalization, assume that ${\bf v}_m \cdot {\bf v}_m = 1$.

Comment: And if $\lambda_m=0$?

Comment: Either ignore the $m$ for which $\lambda_m=0$, or assume that $\lambda_m\not=0$ for all $m$.